# Iterate through the collection and add items in List<T>

Tags: c#, list, class, collections

I have following classes:-

```
public class SiteMapSection
{
    public string sectionUrl { get; set; }
    public List<SiteMapSubSection> subSection { get; set; }
}

public class SiteMapSubSection
{
    public string subSectionUrl { get; set; }
    public List<SiteMapArticle> article { get; set; }
}

public class SiteMapArticle
{
    public string url { get; set; }
}
```

I'm using SiteMapSection class as a Type in the list:-

```
List<SiteMapSection> siteMapSection = new List<SiteMapSection>();
```

Now, i'm trying to add items in 'siteMapSection' list, as given below:-

```
foreach (var section in sections)
{
    .....
    siteMapSection.Add(new SiteMapSection { sectionUrl = section.Url });
    .....
    foreach (var subsection in subsections)
    {
        .....
        siteMapSection.Add(new SiteMapSubSection { ??stuck_here?? });
        .....
        var articles = GetNextArticles(0, subSectionId, true, false);
        .....
        foreach(var article in articles)
        {
            siteMapSection.Add(new SiteMapArticle { ??stuck_here?? });
        }
    }
}
```

How do I iterate through the collection and add items in List siteMapSection.

**Updated Code, this also not works i see only siteMapSection.Add(sms) item got added but other nested still empty**

```
        List<SiteMapSection> siteMapSection = new List<SiteMapSection>();
        SectionArticle sa = new SectionArticle();

        foreach (BE.Section section in Sections.Find(websiteId, parentSectionId))
        {
            int sectionId = section.Id;
            var sms = new SiteMapSection();
            sms.sectionUrl = Sections.VirtualPath(section) + ".aspx";

            var _subsections = new List<SiteMapSubSection>();
            foreach (BE.Section subsection in Sections.Find(websiteId, sectionId))
            {
                int subSectionId = subsection.Id;
                var smss = new SiteMapSubSection();
                smss.subSectionUrl = Sections.VirtualPath(subsection) + ".aspx";

                var articles = sa.GetArticlesForSection(websiteId, subSectionId, 10);
                var _articles = new List<SiteMapArticle>();
                foreach (var article in articles)
                {
                    var sma = new SiteMapArticle();
                    sma.url = article.Code + ".aspx";
                    _articles.Add(sma);
                }
                _subsections.Add(smss);
            }
            siteMapSection.Add(sms);
        }
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on ??stuck_here??. What is the problem?

Comment: @Lee I wanted to add item in the list of type SiteMapSection. First ??stuck_here = subSectionUrl (in SiteMapSubSection), and second stuck_here = url (in SiteMapArticle class)

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that you are trying to add different types to `List<SiteMapSection>`. You can not add different types to a generic list. When creating a list you are defining the types which are allowed in the list, where as you are trying to add different types.

You need to change

```
siteMapSection.Add(new SiteMapSubSection { ??stuck_here?? });
```

to

```
siteMapSection.Add(new SiteMapSection { ??stuck_here?? });
```

If you provide a bit more context perhaps we could give you a better approach in general.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

```
foreach (var section in sections)
{
    .....
    var sms = new SiteMapSection { sectionUrl = section.Url };
    sms.subSection = new List<SiteMapSubSection>();
    .....
    foreach (var subsection in subsections)
    {
        .....
        var smss = new new SiteMapSubSection { subsection }
        ssms.article = new List<SiteMapArticle>();
        .....
        var articles = GetNextArticles(0, subSectionId, true, false);
        .....
        foreach(var article in articles)
        {
            smss.article.Add(new SiteMapArticle { article });
        }
        sms.subSection.Add(ssms);

    }
    siteMapSection.Add(sms);

}
```